# Permutation code in C

Tags: performance, c, programming-challenge, memory-optimization

I am pretty new to competitive programming. It took me almost 3 hours to make this, initially I started with 4 for loops and then to make it scalable for sizes bigger than 4, I decided to turn this into a recursion which is when it took most of my time, even though I am proud of it, I am still worried that it took me an hour to actually come up with the solution and I have a feeling that it is neither efficient nor good, *(you could say I am basically doing combination rather than permutation)*,
**I would like a code review please**
and **how would you make this more efficient**?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int counter = 0;

int factorial(int n){
    if(n==1) return 1;
    else return n*factorial(n-1);
}

int index_present_check(int* n_arr, int n, int depth){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < depth ; i++) if(n_arr[i]==n) return 1;
    return 0; 
}

int present_in_array_check(char** store_arr,char* arr_to_print,int counter){
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++) if(strcmp(store_arr[i],arr_to_print)==0) return 1;
    return 0;
}

void permutation(int depth,int length,char* src_arr, char* arr_to_print,int*     n_arr,char** store_arr){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i ++){
        if(depth ==1){
            arr_to_print[0] = src_arr[i];
            n_arr[0] = i;
            permutation(depth+1,length,src_arr,arr_to_print,n_arr,store_arr);
        }
        else{
            if(!index_present_check(n_arr,i,depth)){
                arr_to_print[depth-1] = src_arr[i];
                n_arr[depth-1] = i;
                permutation(depth+1,length,src_arr,arr_to_print,n_arr,store_arr);
                n_arr[depth-1] = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(depth==length){
        if(!present_in_array_check(store_arr,arr_to_print,counter)){
            printf("%s ",arr_to_print);
            strcpy(store_arr[counter],arr_to_print);
            counter++;
            if(counter%factorial(length-1)==0){
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}



int main()
{
    char* src_arr = "ABCDE";
    int length = 4;
    int depth = 1;

    int iteration_length = factorial(length);

    char* arr_to_print = malloc(length*sizeof(char));
    int* n_arr = malloc(length*sizeof(int));
    char** store_arr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*iteration_length);
    for(int i = 0 ; i<iteration_length;i++) store_arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*length);

    permutation(depth,length,src_arr,arr_to_print,n_arr,store_arr);

    return 0;
}
```

I posted this in reddit too, but it was a bit off timing and didn't get much code review, however it was helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There are only two versions of the `main` function:

   ```
   /* 1 */
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { ... }

   /* 2 */
   int main(void) { ... }
   ```

   Note the `void` keyword in the second version. In C, if the function has no parameters it should be declared as

   ```
    <type> f(void)
   ```

   Please, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29326312/8086115) SO answer for details.
2. Do not write one-line code:

   > ```
   > for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++) if(strcmp(store_arr[i],arr_to_print)==0) return 1;
   > ```

   I'd rewrite it this way:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       if (strcmp(store_arr[i], arr_to_print) == 0)
           return 1;
   ```
3. Do not use `int` as type for array indexing. It is not guaranteed  that `int` can hold any possible index value of an array object. The only type that can hold any index of an array object is `size_t`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2550799/8086115) SO answer for details.
4. I'd replace

   ```
   printf("\n");
   ```

   with

   ```
   putchar('\n');
   ```
5. Do not cast the result of `malloc` call. Really, you have to do it in C++, but not in C. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) SO question for details.
6. Do not repeat yourself. Consider this line:

   > ```
   > int* n_arr = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
   > ```

   You declare `n_arr` as a pointer to `int`. It would be better to rewrite this line in this way:

   ```
   int *n_arr = malloc(length * sizeof *n_arr);
   ```

   In this case you don't have to change the expression of the `sizeof` operator if you change `n_arr` type. It is very common C idiom.
7. Do not computer factorial using recursion. It is *really slow*. Usually, you can just create the factorial table and hardcode it:

   ```
   static const unsigned long long factorial_table[] = {
       1,
       2,
       6,
       24,
       120,
       720,
       ...
   };
   ```
8. In this line:

   > ```
   > char* src_arr = "ABCDE";
   > ```

   you create a pointer to a string literal. It would be better to create just a *static array*:

   ```
   static src_arr[] = "ABCDE";
   ```
9. And you can make it `const` since it never changes:

   ```
   static const src_arr[] = "ABCDE";
   ```

Comment: Amazing, the details of such feedback kind of makes me sad about whether my self learning practices are any good.

Comment: The fact I did not hardcode the factorial was for the fact that I wanted it to be scalable for any length.

Comment: BTW I ran this on hackerrank and out of 48 test cases, 29 of them passed, for the other ones it basically says timed out, so I was wondering is it possible to make this more time and memory efficient ( given that I hardcode the factorial) ?

Comment: @SonGohan, 1) well, you actually can not make factorial computing to be scalable for any length (as long as you are not using bignum arithmetic). 2) permutation is a quite hard topic and I am not very good at it :), so I'd recommend you read [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_in_computing) about this topic and take a look at [StackOverflow Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/permutation).